# Is there a Mapkit Annotation event when the pin is done animating?

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I am having some issues with my Mapkit and userlocation events. I need to call a method when the user's location is found, however, using `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];` causes the method to call too early for what I am trying to do.

Ideally, I would like to make a call once the animation of the user location's pin is completed. Is there any way to watch for that?

Answer (score 1):

In the delegate of your locationManager (which conforms to the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol), implement your method call inside:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;
```

This will be called once the location is resolved.  You may want to make sure it is within your desired accuracy tolerances before taking action:

```
if (newLocation.accuracy <= locationManager.desiredAccuracy ){
```

You may want to perform your action after a delay to allow the animation for the current location to complete.  Apple seems to typically uses between 0.5 and 0.25 for animation durations.